# Why should resistance have an effect on the current of a circuit?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

Ohms law $V=IR$ states that if the resistance of a circuit is to increase, the rate of charge flow at any point in the circuit is decreased. Whilst this seems a simple statement to make, I question why this would be the case. How can resistance, something that causes charges to lose their energy, have any effect on the current of the circuit?

Surely - if anything - lesser resistance would result in a smaller voltage difference which would mean less current.

Comment: The experiments are easy. Reality lies in the phenomena, not in words. So, go do some experiments.

Comment: Ohm's law relates the current through a conductor, the voltage between two points along that conductor, and the resistance between those same two points. You said, "...if the resistance...is to increase, the [current]...is decreased." That's true if the voltage is held constant, but in some circuits it might not be true if swapping out a resistor for one with a different value causes voltages to change. It is especially not true in circuits where active components force a [constant current](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_source) through the resistor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Ohms law $V=IR$ states that if the resistance of a circuit is to
> increase, the rate of charge flow at any point in the circuit is
> decreased.

That's only true if the voltage is fixed (constant).

> How can resistance, something that causes charges to lose their
> energy, have any effect on the current of the circuit?

Because it takes a certain amount of work per unit charge (i.e. voltage) to move the charge through the resistor per unit time. The greater the resistance the greater the work per unit charge (voltage) needed to overcome the resistance and maintain the same charge per unit time through the resistor. Consequently, if the voltage across the resistor is fixed, increasing the resistance will decrease the current.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Because resistance hampers electron mobility $\mu$, which affects electron drift speed by :
$$ v_d=\mu E \tag 1,$$

then [drift speed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drift_velocity) is taken into account when calculating current :

$$ I = v_dneA  \tag 2,$$

where $n$ is electron concentration, $A$ cross-section of wire.

To understand it intuitively,- try to put bunch of heavy stones into a fast flowing river and see what happens to water flow speed having to overcome resistance with stones.